# Returning the group with matching condition

Tags: r, dplyr

hi I'm trying to filter a condition and want to extract it's group.

Something like

```
V <- rnorm(30)
gr = rep(seq(1,3),each=10)
df <- data.frame(V,gr)

min_num <- df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  filter(rank(V,ties.method="min")==1)
```

returning this

```
     V    gr
      (dbl) (int)
1 -1.134910     1
2 -1.598005     2
3 -1.317898     3
```

when I do

```
  filter(V==min(V))
```

also returning the same result. How can I get the group that shows min `V` value. Group number is important. In this case the code should return only 2nd group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `ungruoup` it earlier (if not it returns minimum in each group):

```
min_num %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    filter(V==min(V))
```